# Mustache tamplate can run on node.js but not on Ruby

Tags: node.js, mustache

this recursive Mustache template can run on node.js, but if I run it on ruby, it gives very strange output. Why that happened and how can I fix it?

```
const mustache = require('mustache')

const componentTemplate = `
  <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
  {{#components.length}}
  <ul>{{#components}}<li>{{>componentTemplate}}</li>{{/components}}</ul>
  {{/components.length}}
`;

const view = {
  name: 'System',
  components: [
    { name: 'Display',
      components: [
    { name: 'Monitor 1', components: [] },
    { name: 'Monitor 2', components: [] }
      ]
    },
    { name: 'Processor',
      components: [
    { name: 'CPU', components: [] },
    { name: 'Memory', components: [] },
      ],
    },
    { name: 'Keyboard', components: [] },
    { name: 'Mouse', components: [] }
  ]
};

const partials = {
  componentTemplate: componentTemplate
};
console.log(mustache.render(componentTemplate, view, partials));
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the output you get in Ruby.

Comment: It would be nice if you added the Ruby code, so we could see what you're doing over there...